# How to style <input type="text"> in IE6 CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-selectors

Is there any elegant way of applying a certain style to all `<input type="text">` elements under IE6? I can do it with some JavaScript, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it.

Note - I cannot apply a certain class to all textboxes by hand. And I'd like to [avoid CSS expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516469/ie6-performance-with-css-expressions).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK, IE6 does not support [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), so I think the answer is no.  You'd have to use one of the following:

1. Add a common class attribute to all `<input type="text"/>` elements.
2. Use JavaScript, as you suggested.

Both of which you want to avoid. Too bad.

Comment: jQuery can make javascript styling a lot less painful as it support selection filters very similar with CSS

Comment: @Alertis: true, but it's still javascript.

Comment: It's an internal use web application which depends heavily on JavaScript anyway. Using it for styling is no problem. I just wondered if there was any better way.

Comment: you can use also IE css expressions, eg: `input { _color: expression(this.type=='text' ? 'red' : 'blue'); }`

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to be using jQuery, try adding this to your onDOMready:

```
$('input[type="text"]').addClass('typeText');
```

Then in your CSS you could so something like:

```
input.typeText, input[type="text"] {
     color:#efefef;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have other input elements which you wish to style differently to the "text" element? If not, just apply the style to all input elements with CSS:

```
input {
border: 1px #8194b2 solid;
font : normal 100% "Tahoma", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I indeed wish to leave other <input> types unaffected. I'll be changing things such as height and background-color, so it would reflect pretty nasty on, say, a checkbox.

Comment: Indeed. Since you're only using javascript for some minor styling, I think you can justify using it. It won't affect the functionality for the minority without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Does putting a class attribute on you input element work for you?

> input.text{
>
> //some CSS attributes and values here....
>
> }

- maybe more elegant than JS